# refactoring from controller to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

I have this action in my Order Controller:

```
# POST /orders
# POST /orders.json
def create
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])

  #spostare il ciclo cart > line_items come metodo del modello Order
  cart = session[:cart]

  cart.each do | id, quantity |
    item = Project.find_by_id(id)
    @line_item = LineItem.new
    @line_item.project = item
    @line_item.quantity = quantity
    @line_item.price = item.price
    @order.line_items << @line_item
  end

  @order.user = current_user

  session.delete(:cart)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @order.save
      #Send an email to admin
      UserMailer.order_created_to_admin(@order).deliver

      format.html { redirect_to :dashboard, notice: "L'ordine è stato creato correttamente." }
      format.json { render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

now I want to refactor it a bit, and I'm thinking moving the following lines to Order Model as a method:

```
  cart.each do | id, quantity |
    item = Project.find_by_id(id)
    @line_item = LineItem.new
    @line_item.project = item
    @line_item.quantity = quantity
    @line_item.price = item.price
    @order.line_items << @line_item
  end
```

like that:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items, :allow_destroy => true

  def add_line_items_to_order_from_cart(cart) do
    cart.each do | id, quantity |
      item = Project.find_by_id(id)
      @line_item = LineItem.new
      @line_item.project = item
      @line_item.quantity = quantity
      @line_item.price = item.price
      line_items << @line_item
    end
  end
end
```

and calling it from controller like:

```
order.add_line_items_to_order_from_cart(cart)
```

Does it make sense or not in terms of "skinny controller / fat models" pattern?

thank you

EDIT

My Order model now:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items, :allow_destroy => true
  validates :user, :presence => :true

  def add_line_items_to_order_from_cart(cart)
    cart.each do | id, quantity |
      item = Project.find(id)
      line_items << LineItem.new(project: item,
                                 quantity: quantity,
                                 price: item.price)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Yes, it really make sense! I'm a fan of 'thin controller / fat model' pattern :)

Comment: hi @BlueSmith , thank you! I was thinking that all that "calls" to other models Project and LineItems could be a problem inside a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makes sense to me, you're providing the model with a hash and the model is responsible for parsing the hash and turning it into database records.

A bit cleaner even might be to move the whole line_item thing into one line:

```
def add_line_items_to_order_from_cart(cart) do
  cart.each do |id, quantity|
    item = Project.find_by_id(id)
    line_items << LineItem.new( project: item,
                                quantity: quantity,
                                price: item.price )
  end
end
```

You could even try it this way:

```
def add_line_items_to_order_from_cart(cart) do
  line_items = cart.map do |id, quantity|
    item = Project.find_by_id(id)
    LineItem.new( project: item,
                  quantity: quantity,
                  price: item.price )
  end
end
```

But the general idea is right, move that stuff into the model! ;)

Comment: using `line_items << LineItem.new project: item, quantity: quantity, price: item.price` I get `syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError) ..._items << LineItem.new project: item, quantity: quantity, pr...`

Comment: Line 4 is a syntax error. You need to use parens when passing that LineItem.new.

Comment: Hmm didn't think they were necessary in this case, but let's add them to be sure. ;)